# What's the best way to implement a calculated column?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, optimization

I'm using entity framework 6 and database first approach to build a project,
Assume these 2 tables:

```
Tasks
id | taskName | taskPrice
1  | Making UI| 100
2  | Debugging| 70
```

and the second table:

```
Employees
id | Name | spentHours| taskId | *totalPrice*
1  | Iman | 10        |  2     |  (10 * 70) = 700
2  | Sam  |  5        |  1     |  (5 * 100) = 500
```

I need to make the totalPrice value available to use in all sections of my project, hence it's best not to compute it for each and every use.
In order to achieve this, I have came to these three solutions so far:
1- I could allocate a column to totalPrice and update it's value, which I don't think is the most optimized way, because if taskPrice changes I'll need to recalculate & update the totalPrice values.

2- second method is by using a stored procedure.

3- and third is by using a trigger.

Which method is the most optimized one in terms of computation, over head & time?
If there's any other method of doing so, please let me know.

Comment: A View seem like a good choice here,

Comment: You should not have a computed column in the database. Just have a property in the model that returns the computed value

Comment: @StephenMuecke The problem is that every time I make a new instance of the model, the computation reoccurs.

Comment: Which is exactly how it should be!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, It's the right to be like that, the thing is, I use ALOT of new instances all over my project, say N , now multiply this N to the number of computations and used memory. It's great deal, I'm looking for a way to optimize this matter.

Comment: Add a test method in a loop initialize 1000 new instances of your model (that includes a calculated property). On my laptop it took between 2 or 3 milliseconds. Its insignificant (as is the memory)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your time & effort. Would please share your model source code?

Comment: I just based it on your tables - created a class named `Employee` with properties id, Name spentHours Task (with property taskPrice) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a computed column in DDL.
CREATE TABLE tablname
(
id int,
name varchar(20)
spenthours int,
taskid int,
fn_totalprice(spenthours, id) as totalprcie)

The function can be create function fn_totalprice spenthours int, id int
AS
(
  SELECT (e.spenthours*t.taskprice) as totalprice
   From employees e
   inner join tasks t on e.@id=t.id
     return totalprice
)